# Angular2 - Component keeps running when change page

Tags: angular

I have a large Angular2 app.  I one route I have is `/rewards` which is a list of all rewards we offer.  Another route I have is `/reward/{rewardName}` which is a single reward detail page.  The problem I am having is that when I switch back and fourth between the `/rewards` route and different `/reward/{rewardName}` routes, all of the `/reward/{rewardName}` pages that I have hit continue to run.  i know this because I have a `setInterval` in the `ngOnInit` in my `/reward/{rewardName}` component.  So if I hit the `/reward/{rewardName}` route 5 times, it will log out 5 instances of `quantity`, as shown in code below. Why does this component never stop running? (continues to run no matter what page I go to in rest of site)

Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { RewardDetailService } from './reward-detail.service';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'reward-detail-component',
  styleUrls: [ './reward-detail.component.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './reward-detail.component.html'
})

export class RewardDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    quantity = 1;

    constructor(private rewardsDetailService: RewardDetailService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { ... }

     ngOnInit() {
        setInterval(() => {
          console.log('QUANTITY: ', this.quantity);
        }, 1000) 
      }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate in a way that only a router parameter value is changed, but otherwise the same route is used, the component is not destroyed, but reused.

In 2.3 support for a custom reuse strategy was added to override this behavior.

See also:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13124 which allows to provide a custom reuse strategy.
- https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx

Alternatively you can just subscribe to param changes and do your initialization in the callback:

```
constructor(private rewardsDetailService: RewardDetailService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { 
  router.params.forEach(param => this.myInit(param['rewardName']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, what else would you expect :)? How can angular mysteriously stop your `setInterval` if you do not specify this. Same goes for `eventListeners` and `subscriptions`. You should stop these at `ngOnDestroy`.

```
private _interval: number;

ngOnInit() {
    this._interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('QUANTITY: ', this.quantity);
    }, 1000) 
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this._interval);
}
```